# How to select date in Primefaces <p:calendar/> popup with keyboard

Tags: primefaces, datepicker, calendar

I have the requirement to make an application accessable for handicapped useres, using screenreaders. Now I recognized that a date on the  popup can be selected only with the mouse.

Is there any way to use the keyboard for it? OK, worst case the user can make the input directly into the field but thats not what the customers wants.

Comment: Please provide PF version info?

Comment: <primefaces.version>5.2</primefaces.version>